# IPhone picture gallery source code

Tags: iphone

HI all
 can anyone please refer me, the iphone image gallery source code?
Any link ,sample code will be great help.

i  am trying to show some  70 to 100 images as thumbnails , and on selecting any image, it should give a full view of that image,i am trying to accomplish, whatever is in iphone's picture gallery,
i thought, there must any sample code available. 
 suggestions are always appreciated

regards

Comment: You can add some more points to mention what you need exactly

Comment: edited my question my friend.

Comment: You have the images in local or you want to download in runtime?

Comment: what does the local means it is Bundle or photo library in iphone...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In didload method call two methods to create scroll view and thumbnail button.Keep both thumbnail images and wallpaper images array in the same order.

```
-(void)createScrollView
{
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * (([imagesArray count]- 1) / 25 + 1), 440);

scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}

 -(void)createButton{
for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++) 
{

    thumbNailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    thumbNailButton.frame = CGRectMake(6 + 62 * (i % 5) + 320 * (i / 25), 5+65 * ((i / 5) % 5), 56,56);

    img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 56, 56)];
    [img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    thumbNailButton.tag=i;
    [thumbNailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];   
    [thumbNailButton addSubview:img];
    [scrollView addSubview:thumbNailButton];

}

}

 -(void)imageClicked:(id)sender{
UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate setimageClickedValue:button.tag];

LargeWallPaperviewController *largeWallPaperViewController=[[LargeWallPaperviewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LargeWallPaperviewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:largeWallPaperViewController animated:YES];
[largeWallPaperViewController release];
}
```

In largewallpaperviewcontroller class in didload method

```
   [imagesArray addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wallf1.jpg",@"wallf2.jpg",@"wallf3.jpg",@"wallf4.jpg",@"wallf5.jpg",@"wallf6.jpg",@"wallf7.jpg",nil]];

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 440)];
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * ([imagesArray count] ), 440);
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++) 
{

    wallPaperButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    wallPaperButton.tag=i;
    wallPaperButton.frame=CGRectMake((320*i),0, 320, 325);

    UIImageView *img =[ [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 325)];

    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    img.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;            
    [wallPaperButton addSubview:img];
    [img release];


    [wallPaperButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     [scrollView addSubview:wallPaperButton];
}
appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
int imageValue=[appDelegate getimageClickedValue];
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*imageValue, 0, 320 , 440) animated:NO];
```

i have used a button in the largewallpaer view.If you want you remove it and directly add it to image view.This code is working for me ,change it to your requirement.Its easy to understand.

All the best.

Comment: @warrior.can u help me i need to add 3images of 4 rows in each page .of size 96*96.like that i have 52 images.can u pls help me to correct ur equation according to this requirement.thumbNailButton.frame = CGRectMake(6 + 62 * (i % 5) + 320 * (i / 25), 5+65 * ((i / 5) % 5), 56,56);.I am really struck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Hats off to this code. This works perfectly. Although I have modified the "appdelegate part" since I was using story boards.

Here is what I did

```
-(void)imageClicked:(id)sender{
     UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
     imageNumber =  button.tag;
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadImage" sender:sender];


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loadImage"])
 {

    [segue.destinationViewController setimageValue:imageNumber];
 }
}
```

And in my destination `View Controller.m` file named `'ImageViewController'` I implemented things as below

```
 -(void)setimageValue:(int)number;
 {
     self.imageValue = number;
 }
```

And in  `viewDidLoad`, instead of app delegate I just used

```
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320*self.imageValue, 0, 320 , 440)          animated:NO];
```