# photoview using UIScrollViewController

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, photo

I'm trying to make photo album like photo.app in iPhone. I know We have 'PhotoScroller' example from Apple (which I don't think I can copy and paste the code here due to the Non Disclosure Agreement, plus it's bit biggy to play with at the moment). However I found an another example from random search and it seems like based on the PhotoScroller (very simplified tough). The link for the example is ;
http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/

I applied this code to my project to make photo album (and it scrolls, at least), but I found a problem. The problem is I cannot start from the page I want. The sample code only starts scrolling with Page One. Code itself seems 'really' simple but somehow I just cannot make it start from the page I choose.

Here is main part of the sample code that I found on the Internet. You can of course download the project the link above.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
```

NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: viewDidLoad");
 [super viewDidLoad];

// view controllers are created lazily
    // in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
        [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
    self.viewControllers = controllers;
    [controllers release];

```
// a page is the width of the scroll view
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;

pageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;

// pages are created on demand
// load the visible page
// load the page on either side to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:0];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:1];}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
```

NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: loadScrollViewWithPage");
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

```
// replace the placeholder if necessary


MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
  //
```

[controller release];
    }

```
// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
```

NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: scrollViewDidScroll");

```
// We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
// which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
// the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
if (pageControlUsed) {
    // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
    return;
}

// Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
```

int page = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;

```
// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
```

}

```
// At the begin of scroll dragging, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
```

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
 NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: scrollViewWillBeginDragging");
    pageControlUsed = NO;
}

```
    // At the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
```

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: scrollViewDidEndDecelerating");
 pageControlUsed = NO;
}

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender {
```

NSLog(@"ScrollViewWithPagingViewContrller :: changePage");
    int page = pageControl.currentPage;

```
// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];
```

// update the scroll view to the appropriate page
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];

// Set the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl. See scrollViewDidScroll: above.
    pageControlUsed = YES;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is

scrollView1.contentOffset = CGPointMake( , );

quite simple. spent lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented photo album view where in first view i have shown all the thumbnail images and on clicking each image it gives its full screen view. you also scroo the images.
[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012062/iphone-picture-gallery-source-code/4049085#4049085).

All the best.

Comment: god...pasting code is really pain in the bu*t. thanks for the answer Warrior. I'll take a look.

Comment: I also have thumbnail view that holds 12 thumbnails. Each thumbnail is UIButton, when pressed->flip view-> large picture view. and then swap using UIScrollViewController. that's my plan. I just looked your code and...I have no idea where to start. do you have sample code somewhere?

Comment: create two class  and paste the code i have provided.  i can help you out if you have doubts in integrating.If you still have more problem i will try to send you some sample code.Give your mail id..

Comment: um...my first question is ...we have two scrollview setups. from your answer...first block of code and the second one has respectively. is it right?